# vertical navigation bar with dropdown menus

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I would like to receive some assistance with a code. I need recommendations for menu code, vertical menus, a menu that can be opened and closed with the help of an icon beside it. I also need this menu to have a dropdown function for each topic, for example, "Social media > Telegram," but I need it to have 3 levels of menus: "menu," "sub-menu," and "sub-sub-menu." Could you help me with this? It can be jQuery code, no problem.

I have already tried to create the menu myself using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, but the results were far from pleasing. There are many bugs and errors that I simply can't comprehend.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would recommend checking out [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: "*I have already tried to create the menu myself*" - excellent! Please, as imvain2 has discreetly suggested, share your best attempt with us, then we can offer an answer tailored to your specific situation. Also, "*...the results were far from pleasing. There are many bugs and errors...*" - you need to tell us what these "bugs" and "errors" are, what happened? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: i cant send my code here, so i made a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/ChBkKWz4

Comment: You can absolutely post your "*[mcve]*" code here, and you can also [edit] your question to post that code, and answer the various other questions I asked in my previous comment. Don't worry about formatting the code, if that's where you're struggling, we can assist with that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

try this one : [Click link](https://codepen.io/anu_mistry/pen/zYyMzgb)

```
HTML :

<nav class='animated bounceInDown'>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='#Menu1'>Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href='#Menu2'>Menu 2</a></li>
        <li class='sub-menu'><a href='#Menu3'>Menu 3<div class='fa fa-caret-down right'></div></a>
            <ul>
                <li class='sub-menu'><a href='#Menu3.1'>Menu 3.1 <div class='fa fa-caret-down right'></div></a>
                  <ul>
            <li><a href='#Menu3.1.1'>Menu 3.1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href='#Menu3.1.2'>Menu 3.1.2</a></li>
            <li><a href='#Menu3.1.3'>Menu 3.1.3</a></li>
          </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href='#Menu3.2'>Menu 3.2</a></li>
                <li><a href='#Menu3.3'>Menu 3.3</a></li>
                <li><a href='#Menu3.4'>Menu 3.4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class='sub-menu'><a href='#Menu4'>Menu 4<div class='fa fa-caret-down right'></div></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href='#Menu4.1'>Menu 4.1</a></li>
                <li><a href='#Menu4.2'>Menu 4.2</a></li>
                <li><a href='#Menu4.3'>Menu 4.3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href='#Menu5'>Menu 5</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>


CSS : 

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
}
nav {
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px;
    width: 360px;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    background: #ebebeb;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: 0.2s linear;
    -ms-transition: 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: 0.2s linear;
    transition: 0.2s linear;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #f8f8f8;
    color: #515151;
}
nav ul li a .fa {
    width: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 5px;
    float:right;
}
nav ul ul {
    background-color:#ebebeb;
}

JS :

$('.sub-menu ul').hide();
$(".sub-menu a").click(function () {
    $(this).parent(".sub-menu").children("ul").slideToggle("100");
    $(this).find(".right").toggleClass("fa-caret-up fa-caret-down");
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).